# Python Regex MULTILINE option not working correctly?

Tags: python, regex, replace, find, multiline

I'm writing a simple version updater in Python, and the regex engine is giving me mighty troubles.

In particular, ^ and $ aren't matching correctly even with re.MULTILINE option. The string matches without the ^ and $, but no joy otherwise.

I would appreciate your help if you can spot what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

**target.c**

```
somethingsomethingsomething
    NOTICE_TYPE revision[] = "A_X1_01.20.00";
somethingsomethingsomething
```

**versionUpdate.py**

```
fileName = "target.c"
newVersion = "01.20.01"
find = '^(\s+NOTICE_TYPE revision\[\] = "A_X1_)\d\d+\.\d\d+\.\d\d+(";)$'
replace = "\\1" + newVersion + "\\2"

file = open(fileName, "r")
fileContent = file.read()
file.close()

find_regexp = re.compile(find, re.MULTILINE)
file = open(fileName, "w")
file.write( find_regexp.sub(replace, fileContent) )
file.close()
```

**Update**: Thank you John and Ethan for a valid point. However, the regexp still isn't matching if I keep $. It works again as soon as I remove $.

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) If you're matching a single line, why do you need `re.MULTILINE`? 2) Are there spaces after the `;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your replace to:

```
replace = r'\g<1>' + newVersion + r'\2'
```

The problem you're having is your version results in this:

```
replace = "\\101.20.01\\2"
```

which is confusing the sub call as there is no field 101.  From the documentation for the Python [re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

> \g<number> uses the corresponding group number; \g<2> is therefore
>   equivalent to \2, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as \g<2>0.
>   \20 would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference
>   to group 2 followed by the literal character '0'.

Answer (score 2):

if you do a `print replace` you'll see the problem...

```
replace == '\\101.20.01\2'
```

and since you don't have a 101st match, the first portion of your line gets lost.  Try this instead:

```
newVersion = "_01.20.01"
find = r'^(\s+NOTICE_TYPE revision\[\] = "A_X1)_\d\d+\.\d\d+\.\d\d+(";)$'
replace = "\\1" + newVersion + "\\2"
```

(moves a portion of the match so there is no conflict)